# Как отправить во Vue.js get запрос в контроллер laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Подскажите, как отправить get-запрос vue.js в контроллер laravel, то есть чтобы записать данные в методе get (Route::get).
Пробовал через axios, в итоге не работает.

```
methods: {
    handleSwitch(){
        axios.get("/", { sequence:item.name }).then((response)=> { console.log(item.name) });
                 }
         }
```

Установил уже даже `Vue resource`, что-то тоже пробывал и не работает. 
Повторюсь, у меня все уже готово, только нужно чтобы в get-запрос отправились данные, и выполнить постановку без обновления страницы.

Comment: Ну документация гласит, что get-параметры передаются в params... axios.get('/', { params : {sequence:item.name} })

Comment: Пробовал уже, не катит. Вообще запрос не доходит. Где-то читал что нужно типо через заголовки только посылать

Comment: Попробуй для начала не в laravel посылать, а в простой php файл. Дело в том, что сам laravel как то по особому обрабатывает запросы, а так этот код должен работать (у меня похожий используется: `axios.get('/', { params : {sequence:item.name} })`).

Comment: Я не намекаю, но мало ли, а вы уверены что у вас путь правильны ? в в каком файле заполняли ? web.php или api.php, потому как елси в api.php то путь туда будет не `/`, а минимум '/api/'

Comment: В web.php. Api вообще не понимаю,  как через него.
Пути правильные, response работает (когда post запрос отправляю)